# Formula to calculate Price of Service

Tags: percentages

I would like some help in elaborating a formula for a service I will be providing to a retailer's client.

In simple terms, I would be paid a $5\%$ percentage over the price of the client's purchase, with a minimum cost of service of $2$ and a maximum of $10$.

It is important to say the comission would be paid by the client, so the amount would be added to the client's total cost.

Here are some examples:

If a client makes a purchase of $20$ and picks the service, he will pay a total of $22$;

If a client makes a purchase of $40$, he will pay a total of $42$.

If a client makes a purchase of $80$, he will pay a total of $84$.

If a client makes a purchase of $199$, he will pay a total of $208.95$.

If a client makes a purchase of $1000$, he will pay a total of $1010$.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this has nothing to do with 'logic' as far as the tag description goes: Why don't you just define your function precisely the way you described them to us? I.e. $f(x) = x+2$ for $0 \le x <40$, $f(x) = 1.05 \cdot x$ for $40 \le x < 200$ and $f(x) = x+10$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand the cost of your service is:
$$
\begin{cases}
y=2 \qquad  \qquad \qquad\qquad \quad for\qquad 0<x\le 40\\
y=2+0.05(x-40) \qquad for \qquad 40<x\le 200\\
y=10 \qquad  \qquad \qquad\qquad  for\qquad x>200
\end {cases}
$$
If you want you can express this with asingle expression as
$$
y=10+0.5(2+0.5(0.05(x-40)+|0.05(x-40)|)-10-|2+0.5(0.05(x-40)+|0.05(x-40)|)-10|)
$$
( see the graph [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2010%2B0.5%282%2B0.5%280.05%28x-40%29%2B%7C0.05%28x-40%29%7C%29-10-%7C2%2B0.5%280.05%28x-40%29%2B%7C0.05%28x-40%29%7C%29-10%7C%29%20from%200%20to%20250)) and add this to the purchase, but it does not seems a good idea to me.